# Error with TypeScript Generics (Using `Partial<T>` for `? super T`)

Tags: typescript, undefined, nullable, typescript-generics, super

TypeScript compilation fails due to an error related to generics that I can not explain. I have created a minimal example:

```
interface Processor<T> { process(data:T):void; }
class ArrayProcessor<T> implements Processor<Array<T>|null> { process(data:Array<T>|null):void {} }
  // intention (Java syntax, TS?): ... `implements Processor<List<? extends T>/*|null*/>` ...
const applyProcessor = <T,>(processor:Processor<Partial<T>>) => {};
  // intention (Java syntax, TS?): ... `<T> void applyProcessor(Processor<? super T> processor)` ...

applyProcessor<Array<number>>(new ArrayProcessor<number>());
//                      ERROR ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The last line produces an error with this message:

```
Argument of type 'ArrayProcessor<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Processor<(number | undefined)[]>'.
  Types of property 'process' are incompatible.
    Type '(data: number[] | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(data: (number | undefined)[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'data' are incompatible.
        Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
          Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

I tried to investigate what TypeScript considers assignable. The `|null` part might have an influence here:

```
const myArg1:Processor<Partial<Array<number>|null>> = new ArrayProcessor<number>(); // <- No error
const myArg2:Processor<Partial<Array<number>>> = new ArrayProcessor<number>(); // <- ERROR
// Type 'ArrayProcessor<number>' is not assignable to type 'Processor<(number | undefined)[]>'.(2322)
```

Why does the `applyProcessor` call fail? Where are these `undefined` in the error messages coming from? How could the first snippet be fixed?

Bonus question: Does TypeScript have an equivalent to Java's `<? super T>`? I would be happy to declare my intention ("... is processor / comparator / consumer / handler / ... of ...") without compilation errors even if the TypeScript compiler can not actually enforce the constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `Partial`.

When you use `Partial` and explicit `number` generic argument `new ArrayProcessor<number>()` it causes an error because `Partial` applies `undefined` type. `undefined` is not the same as `null`.

According to this type definition  `implements Processor<Array<T> | null` you expect an array or null for `Processor` generic while `Processor<Partial<T>>` means that you expect smth different.

In order to fix it, you can rewrite `applyProcessor` function:

```js
const applyProcessor = <T,>(processor: Processor<T | null>) => { };
```

OR

```js
const applyProcessor = <T,>(processor: Processor<T>) => { };
```

Full code:

```js
interface Processor<T> {
  process(data: T): void;
}

class ArrayProcessor<T> implements Processor<Array<T> | null> {
  process(data: Array<T> | null) { }
}

const applyProcessor = <T,>(processor: Processor<T|null>) => { };

applyProcessor(new ArrayProcessor<number>());
```

Comment: Both suggestions compile. TS does not currently prevent `applyProcessor<Animal>(catProcessor)` (which could fail at runtime on `catProcessor.process(dog)`). I can live with that for now.

Comment: My fear is the following: generally writing `X` in TS when I would write `<? super X>` in Java will sooner or later confuse the TS compiler (?). Maybe writing `unknown` for `<? super X>` would be more appropriate?